# my car wont start when the engine is warm

Tags: peugeot

i drive a 307 55plate 2lt diesel, it starts in a morning when the engine is cold, drives perfect, then once stopped it wont start again. I can turn it on n off several times first thing, just after a drive it wont start again. this has allcome about after having a new crank sesor fitted the same time as having the timing belt done.  I was then advised to have the cam sensor changed, still does the same. Any help or advice greatly appreciated.
thankyou

Comment: Note to those not in UK: 55 plate means late 2005 or early 2006.

Answer (score 1):

Check the engine temperature sensor used by the ECU.

If it starts all the time with engine cold, but never with engine warm, it may be the case that the temperature sensor is feeding false data to the ECU. It means the ECU thinks the engine is cold when it is actually warm. Then when the engine cools, the ECU thinks the engine is cold -- quite correctly!

I don't think the crank / cam sensors should affect the workings of the engine in the described manner. It's pretty hard to imagine an engine running perfectly when warm with a crank / cam sensor not working, and then if you stop it, it not starting again. Either it wouldn't run or it would start just fine. On the other hand, the temperature sensor is obviously temperature dependent.

This of course doesn't mean you should jump directly into replacing the temperature sensor. Just a wild idea, and something to check.

Comment: thankyou, i will get that looked at, i know its an old car but it runs lovely, when its running

Comment: My car is 2005 as well, good when looked after...